# Puzzle about using Axios Cache Interceptor

Tags: javascript, caching, axios, frontend

I'm looking for a cache mechanism for http request in my frontend project these days and I found [Axios Cache Interceptor](https://axios-cache-interceptor.js.org/) fit my project, but the problem I have now is that most of the APIs in my project is using `post` method to fetch data instead of `get`.

so, when I use `axios.post`, the cache doesn't work:

```js
const req1 = await axios.post('/api-1', body);
const req2 = await axios.post('/api-2', body);
console.log(req1.cached) // false
console.log(req2.cached) // false
```

how can I make cache work using `axios.post`? please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use post method in intercepted.
Please read this
https://axios-cache-interceptor.js.org/config/request-specifics#cache-methods

also consider https://axios-cache-interceptor.js.org/config#headerinterpreter

```
import { setupCache } from 'axios-cache-interceptor';
import Axios from 'axios';

const axiosCached = setupCache(Axios);

axiosCached.post('http://exampleapi.com/', {
        //parameter
      },{cache: {interpretHeader:false,methods:['post']}})
.then(res => {
  //logic
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

default headerinterpreter reads header from the response and not cache post request. then disable it `{cache: {interpretHeader:false}}`